# Django with MongoDB can't get django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Is it true that it's a bad choice python with non-relational database like MongoDB ?

I heard if i use mongoDB as my database in my djanog project i can't use default admin panel of django in my projects as it's designed with Relational database m ethology ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use mongoDB with all Django features. Checkout Django non-rel documentation and decide yourself. http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: But i heard i can't use django-admin if i use mongoDB

Comment: I recommend you to go over the non-rel documentation and troubleshooting. There are few issues when using MongoDB with Django but most of them have workarounds. For your concern about editing and creating objects through Django-Admin, you'll get DatabaseError cause Django-Admin tries to execute JOIN when querying user's groups and permissions. The solution that non-rel recommend is to add 'djangotoolbox' to your INSTALLED_APPS and by that make Django-Admin skip the groups and permissions widgets.
Hope that it helps!